# How to assign to each button his own calendar? asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm creating a web site, where I have a list of classes, and I want that each class will have **it`s own calendar**. What I mean is, when I click button 1, I will go to a separate calendar then button 2 and so on.
I already have a working calendar, I just don't understand how assign to each button a calendar.
[image: the button is the blue one]

So I have a working calendar with options of add/delete/update events, but I don't understand how to connect them.
I'm on this problem over a week now, and I couldn't find any solution. help please.

This is the index.cshtml where the classes are created: (classes view)

```
    @model IEnumerable<ClasSaver.Models.ClassesModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<style>
    .button {
        background-color: deepskyblue; /* Green */
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Building)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.How_Many_In_Class)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Building)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.How_Many_In_Class)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            <input id="@item.Id" type="button" onclick="parent.open('https://www.google.com/')" value="Open in new window" class="button"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<script>
    
</script>
```

and the controller

```
    using ClasSaver.Data;
using ClasSaver.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ClasSaver.Controllers
{
    public class ClassesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Classes
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<ClassesModel> classes = new List<ClassesModel>();
            ClassDAO classDao = new ClassDAO();
             classes = classDao.FetchAll();
             return View("Index",classes);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            ClassDAO classesDAO = new ClassDAO();
            ClassesModel classes = classesDAO.FetchOne(id);

            return View("Details", classes);
        }

        public ActionResult Create(ClassesModel classesModel)
        {
            return View("ClassesForm", classesModel);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProcessCreate(ClassesModel classesModel)
        {
            //save to DB
            ClassDAO classesDAO = new ClassDAO();
            classesDAO.CreateOrUpdate(classesModel);
            return View("Details", classesModel);
        }
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            ClassDAO classesDAO = new ClassDAO();
            ClassesModel classes = classesDAO.FetchOne(id);
            return View("ClassesForm", classes);
        }
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            ClassDAO classesDAO = new ClassDAO();
            classesDAO.Delete(id);
            List<ClassesModel> classes  = classesDAO.FetchAll();
            return View("Index", classes);
        }

    
        public ActionResult SearchForm()
        {
            return View("SearchForm");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult searchForName(string searchPhrase)
        {

            ClassDAO classesDAO = new ClassDAO();
            List<ClassesModel> searchResults = classesDAO.SearchForName(searchPhrase);

            return View("Index", searchResults);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is where the calendar is created index.cshtml: (home view)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="calender"></div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
                </button>
                <button id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
                </button>
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="myModalSave" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Save Event</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdEventID" value="0" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtSubject" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Start</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="dtp1">
                            <input type="text" id="txtStart" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkIsFullDay" checked="checked" />  Is Full Day event</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="divEndDate" style="display:none">
                        <label>End</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="dtp2">
                            <input type="text" id="txtEnd" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <textarea id="txtDescription" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Theme Color</label>
                        <select id="ddThemeColor" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Default</option>
                            <option value="red">Red</option>
                            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                            <option value="black">Black</option>
                            <option value="green">Green</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section Scripts{

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var events = [];
            var selectedEvent = null;
            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
            function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
                events = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/home/GetEvents",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                eventID: v.EventID,
                                title: v.Subject,
                                description: v.Description,
                                start: moment(v.Start),
                                end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                                color: v.ThemeColor,
                                allDay: v.IsFullDay
                            });
                        })

                        GenerateCalender(events);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('failed');
                    }
                })
            }

            function GenerateCalender(events) {
                $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                    contentHeight: 400,
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: '#378006',
                    events: events,
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        selectedEvent = calEvent;
                        $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                        var $description = $('<div/>');
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        if (calEvent.end != null) {
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                        $('#myModal').modal();
                    },
                    selectable: true,
                    select: function (start, end) {
                        selectedEvent = {
                            eventID: 0,
                            title: '',
                            description: '',
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: false,
                            color: ''
                        };
                        openAddEditForm();
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    eventDrop: function (event) {
                        var data = {
                            EventID: event.eventID,
                            Subject: event.title,
                            Start: event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
                            End: event.end != null ? event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : null,
                            Description: event.description,
                            ThemeColor: event.color,
                            IsFullDay: event.allDay
                        };
                        SaveEvent(data);
                    }
                })
            }

            $('#btnEdit').click(function () {
                //Open modal dialog for edit event
                openAddEditForm();
            })
            $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
                if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/home/DeleteEvent',
                        data: { 'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status) {
                                //Refresh the calender
                                FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            $('#dtp1,#dtp2').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'
            });
            $('#chkIsFullDay').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#divEndDate').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('#divEndDate').show();
                }
            });
            function openAddEditForm() {
                if (selectedEvent != null) {
                    $('#hdEventID').val(selectedEvent.eventID);
                    $('#txtSubject').val(selectedEvent.title);
                    $('#txtStart').val(selectedEvent.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'));
                    $('#chkIsFullDay').prop("checked", selectedEvent.allDay || false);
                    $('#chkIsFullDay').change();
                    $('#txtEnd').val(selectedEvent.end != null ? selectedEvent.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : '');
                    $('#txtDescription').val(selectedEvent.description);
                    $('#ddThemeColor').val(selectedEvent.color);
                }
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#myModalSave').modal();
            }
            $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                //Validation/
                if ($('#txtSubject').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Subject required');
                    return;
                }
                if ($('#txtStart').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Start date required');
                    return;
                }
                if ($('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') == false && $('#txtEnd').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('End date required');
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    var startDate = moment($('#txtStart').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                    var endDate = moment($('#txtEnd').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                    if (startDate > endDate) {
                        alert('Invalid end date');
                        return;
                    }
                }

                var data = {
                    Id: $('#hdEventID').val(),
                    Subject: $('#txtSubject').val().trim(),
                    Start: $('#txtStart').val().trim(),
                    End: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') ? null : $('#txtEnd').val().trim(),
                    Description: $('#txtDescription').val(),
                    ThemeColor: $('#ddThemeColor').val(),
                    IsFullDay: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked')
                }
                SaveEvent(data);
                // call function for submit data to the server
            })
            function SaveEvent(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/home/SaveEvent',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            //Refresh the calender
                            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                            $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

and the controller

```
using ClasSaver.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ClasSaver.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
            using (ClassaverDBEntities2 dc = new ClassaverDBEntities2())
            {
                var events = dc.Events.ToList();
                return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e)
        {
            var status = false;
            using (ClassaverDBEntities2 dc = new ClassaverDBEntities2())
            {
                if (e.EventID > 0)
                {
                    //Update the event
                    var v = dc.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        v.Subject = e.Subject;
                        v.Start = e.Start;
                        v.End = e.End;
                        v.Description = e.Description;
                        v.IsFullDay = e.IsFullDay;
                        v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dc.Events.Add(e);
                }
                dc.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeleteEvent(int eventID)
        {
            var status = false;
            using (ClassaverDBEntities2 dc = new ClassaverDBEntities2())
            {
                var v = dc.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == eventID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    dc.Events.Remove(v);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you linking the calendar to the class? What does your data model look like? When you open your calendar link you need to pass an Id of some description which will allow you to return all the events for a specific calendar.

Comment: @melkisadek I followed this (http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2017/06/event-calendar-in-aspnet-mvc.html) tutorial, and i Showed the calendar in the Index.cshtml of homeController

Comment: So how are you linking your calendar to your class? The Classes page has a link opening a new window at https://www.google.com/. How does that relate to your Home/Index page?

Comment: @melkisadek the google.com is just example for me to how i want the button to look. I linked the calender to the Index of home controller and display it there.

Comment: You're just calling GetEvents() in Home though which returns every event. You need to call e.g. GetEvents(1) and GetEvents(2) and amend the method to accept the Id of the class you want the events for. This will then return a subset of the events based on the class Id you've passed in (assuming all other code is amended to follow suit).

Comment: @melkisadek I don't understand how to implements this, can u help me with this please?

Comment: There isn't enough information to give a workable answer. How does an event get assigned to a class? Does a class have a collection of events or does and event have a single classId and map one-to-one? Do you want an event to be shared between classes?  If you add your Classes class and your Events class to the question it might make some of this clearer.